# Event Sourcing: Read Model Normalized or Denormalized

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, cqrs, event-sourcing

In Event Sourcing, should Read Model Projection be Normalized (relational) or Denormalized (wide-horizontal)? Company is using two SQL Server 2016 databases:, WriteLogDatabase and ReadProjectionDatabase. (Company currently does Not have NoSQL MongoDB, which would help)

In financial company, we import flat files (multiple 1 line client records), applying business filter, validate, transform logic, and API inserting them into Multiple Tables : Customer Address, Customer Loan Type, Customer Phone, Customer Financial Statements. When we get a new line in future flat file, we have to rejoin all the tables into 1 line again, extract all data, make corresponding updates, and feed data back into multiple tables. Just wondering if its better in Event Sourcing to put everything in 1 wide horizontal denormalized method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In event sourcing your events are a source of truth, and your read models are computed from these events.
You can compute both normalized and denormalized read models - the choice is up to you.

Read models should be optimized for read/query operations. So if denormalized read model lets you avoid a join on read - use it.

On the other hand, if your read model is used for some free-form analytic and reporting tool, normalized form could be more convenient for users.